# Porque NaN ^ NaN == 0?

Tags: javascript

Vejam esses testes que fiz no console do navegador:

```
NaN / NaN
NaN

NaN * NaN
NaN

typeof NaN
"number"

NaN ** NaN
NaN

NaN ^ NaN
0
```

Porque exatamente isso acontece?

Comment: E por que `NaN == NaN` dá `false`?

Comment: E porque ```NaN ^ 2 == 2```?

Comment: De onde viemos? Pra onde vamos?

Comment: Minha nossa! kkkkkkkk js tem umas bizarrices tambem hein :p

Comment: Tudo questão de verificar como é comparado em binário que é possível verificar o por que disso!

Comment: @diegofm http://jswtf.tumblr.com/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

De acordo com a [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN):

> **NaN** - A propriedade global NaN é um valor especial que significa Not-A-Number (não é um número).

De acordo com as especificações [ECMAScript 5](http://es5.github.io/) (índice 9.5) e [ECMA 262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) (índice 7.1.5), quando fazemos uma [operação bit a bit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) todos os elementos envolvidos são convertidos para inteiros de 32 bits ([ToInt32](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_reference/JS::ToInt32)). Se o valor for uma das propriedades globais [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) ou [infinity](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity) o valor é convertido para 0.

> **2**. If number is **NaN**, +0, ‑0, +∞, or ‑∞, return +0.

Sabendo que o operador `^` representa a operação lógica `XOR`...

`NaN ^ NaN` é equivalente à `0 XOR 0`

```js
console.log("NaN ^ NaN: " + (NaN ^ NaN));
console.log("0 ^ 0: " + (0 ^ 0));
console.log("Infinity ^ 0: " + (Infinity ^ 0));
```

Answer (score 19):

**Conceito:**

***O que é NaN***

**NaN** é uma propriedade do objeto global. O valor inicial de NaN é **Not-A-Number**, o mesmo valor de `Number.NaN`.

Nos navegadores, o NaN é uma propriedade somente leitura e não configurável. Mesmo quando não for este o caso, evite sobrescrevê-lo.

***Testando um valor NaN***

Os operadores de igualdade (== e ===) não podem ser usados para testar um valor NaN. Ao invés disso, utilize `Number.isNaN()` ou `isNaN()`.

```
NaN === NaN;        // falso
Number.NaN === NaN; // falso
isNaN(NaN);         // verdadeiro
isNaN(Number.NaN);  // verdadeiro
```

[Fonte](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)

***Porta XOR***

**Ou exclusivo** ou **disjunção exclusiva**, conhecido geralmente por **XOR** ou por **EXOR** (também XOU ou EOU), é uma operação lógica entre dois operandos que resulta em um valor lógico verdadeiro se e somente se exatamente um dos operandos possui valor verdadeiro. Pode ser sintetizado como um detector de diferenças entre dois operandos lógicos. [Fonte](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porta_XOR)

**JavaScript**

***Operadores bit a bit***

*XOR    (a ^ b)*

Retorna um 0 para cada posição em que os bits da posição correspondente são os mesmos.
[Retorna um 1 para cada posição em que os bits da posição correspondente sejam diferentes.]

Conceitualmente, os operadores bit a bit lógicos funcionam da seguinte maneira:

- Os operandos são convertidos em inteiros de 32 bits e expressos como
  uma série de bits (zeros e uns). Números com representação maior que
  32 bits terão seus bits truncados. Por exemplo, o seguinte inteiro
  tem representação binária maior que 32 bits será convertido em um
  inteiro de 32 bits.

> - Antes: 11100110111110100000000000000110000000000001
> - Depois:            10100000000000000110000000000001

- Cada bit do primeiro operando é pareado com o bit correspondente do
  segundo operando: primeiro bit com primeiro bit, segundo bit com
  segundo bit e assim por diante.
- O operador é aplicado a cada par de bits e o resultado é construído
  bit a bit.

Por exemplo, a representação binária de nove é 1001 e a representação binária de quinze é 1111. Desta forma, quando operadores bit a bit são aplicados a estes valores, os resultados são como se segue:

Exemplo:

> Expressão: 15 ^ 9
>
> Resultado: 6
>
> Comparação em binário: 1111 ^ 1001
>
> Resultado em binário: 0110

[Fonte](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

**RESPOSTA**

Como NaN é Not-A-Number, não é possível executar operações aritméticas, pois sempre irá resultar em NaN.

```
NaN / NaN
NaN

NaN * NaN
NaN

NaN ** NaN
NaN
```

Nos operadores bit a bit, como exemplo, o XOR ele irá comparar NaN sendo sempre como 0.

```
NaN ^ NaN // 0 ^ 0
0
```

E quando comparar `NaN ^ 2` estará comparando 00B com 10B (B = Binário), retornando 10B que convertendo para decimal é 2

Answer (score 13):

No caso dos operadores aritméticos, NaN não é passível de cálculo e, qualquer valor com um desses operadores utilizado em parceria com NaN, retornará NaN. Já que NaN não é um número.

```
NaN + 1 = NaN

NaN / 2 = NaN
```

No caso do XOR, que é um operador bit a bit, você pode testar o cálculo com base em:

- Para cada bit na mesma posição e com mesmo valor, resulta: 0;
- Para cada bit na mesma posição e com valor diferente, resulta: 1.

`NaN ^ NaN = 0`

Supondo:

`NaN = 0` então:

```
0 ^ 0 = 0
```

Se tu testar:

`1 ^ 2  =  3`, porque?

Vejamos através da representação binária de 1 e 2:

- 1 = 0001;
- 2 = 0010;

Aplicando a lógica XOR:

- 1ª pos 1 = `0` e 1º pos 2 = `0` = `0`;
- 2º pos 1 = `0` e 2º pos 2 = `0` = `0`;
- 3º pos 1 = `0` e 3º pos 2 = `1` = `1`;
- 4º pos 1 = `1` e 4º pos 2 = `0` = `1`;

logo: `0001 ^ 0010 = 0011`, onde `0011` é a representação binária do número 3.

Answer (score 6):

A propriedade global NaN é um valor especial que significa Not-A-Number (não é um número).

Ao contrário de todas as outras possibilidades de valores no JavaScript, não é possível confiar nos operadores de igualdade (== e ===) para determina se o valor é NaN ou não, porque ambos, NaN == NaN e NaN === NaN, terá como valor de retorno: false. Daí a necessidade da funçao isNAN 'isNAN()'.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN

Answer (score 2):

> `NaN ^ NaN = 0` Porque exatamente isso acontece?

**Por preguiça, esquecimento, bug, acaso!**

`NaN ^ NaN`  devia dar `NaN`

A operação `NaN ^ NaN` não faz grande sentido -- operações bit a bit com
valores "descontrolados" não foram previstos por quem fez essa implementação da linguagem, fazendo com que a implementação por omissão
fosse usada.

A implementação por omissão pode ser uma de duas hipóteses:

**h1)** comparação de coerção para inteiros:

```
int(NaN) ^ int(NaN) => 0 ^ 0 => 0
```

**h2)** xor bib a bit directo:
Na representação de números em vírgula flutuante, foi escolhida uma representação convencionada para NaN, associada a um conjunto de bits.
Ao fazer XOR bit a bit de dois grupos iguais dá 0