# Variável JS retornando NaN

Tags: javascript, html, nan

Estou atribuindo a soma de uma coluna em uma tabela HTML a uma variável JS (sum), porém quando imprimo ela na tela recebo um NaN, alguém sabe por que?

```
<tr>
  <td style="background:#c4ffd6;" align="center" class="qtd_recuperado">
        <?php echo "$recuperado_total"; ?>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Depois, no JS, faço a soma:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function sumQuantity() {

       var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('qtd_recuperado');
       var sum = 0;



       for (i=0;i< elements.length;i++) {
         sum = sum + parseFloat(elements[i].innerHTML);
       };

      document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = sum;
      }

       sumQuantity();
  </script>
```

Então tento imprimir, assim:

```
<td style="background:#c4ffd6;" align="center" class="qtd_recuperado" id="resultado"></td>
```

Comment: Podes colocar aqui o HTML que chega ao browser? (ou seja depois do PHP). E já agora, se geras isso no PHP e é HTML estático porque não fazes a soma no PHP também?

Comment: Eu consegui fazer a soma usando o JS, o problema esta na hora de mostrar, por isso não fiz em PHP.

Comment: Ok, então a soma funciona como queres mas inserir dentro de `#resultado` 
 não?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/211239/57801

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como o [Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/129/sergio) comentou, se seu `HTML` é estático então a melhor solução é efetuar a soma pelo `PHP`.

Agora veja que o problema na sua solução com `javascript` ocorre devido ao conteúdo da sua coluna, entenda a função **parseFloat:**

> **parseFloat** analisa um argumento string, e retorna um numero de
>   ponto flutuante. Se ele encontrar um carácter diferente de um sinal
>   (+ ou -), numeral (0-9), um ponto decimal, ou um expoente, ele
>   retorna o valor até esse ponto e ignora esse caractere e todos os
>   caracteres seguintes. Espaços a direita e a esquerda são permitidos.
>
> **Se o primeiro carácter não puder ser convertido para um número, parseFloat retorna NaN**

Veja o exemplo abaixo, adicionei um `IF` para evitar o erro.

```js
function sumQuantity() {
  var elements= document.getElementsByClassName("qtd_recuperado");
  var sum = 0;
  var conteudo;
   
   for (i=0;i< elements.length;i++) {
     conteudo = elements[i].innerHTML;
     if(!isNaN(conteudo))
      sum += parseFloat(conteudo);
   };

document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = sum;
}

sumQuantity();
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="background:#c4ffd6;" align="center" class="qtd_recuperado">
         112
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background:#c4ffd6;" align="center" class="qtd_recuperado">
        10aa
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div>
  <!-- conteudo: 11       -> retorna soma -->
  <!-- conteudo: 11Texto  -> retorna soma -->
  <!-- conteudo: Texto1   -> retorna NaN  -->
  <!-- conteudo: VAZIO    -> retorna NaN  -->
  Resultado: <span id="resultado"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado Caique, mesmo com esse código o valor continua saindo como NaN, porém consegui resolver voltando uma posição no meu length. Acontece que o JS estava somando o conteúdo da <td> que estava em branco, por isso o NaN. Mas, obrigado de qualquer maneira.

Comment: Acontece que a variável que você criou (conteudo), também esta recebendo um valor em branco, por isso continua o NaN.

Comment: Foi intencional eu  coloquei somente como exemplo para você entender o porque de exibir NaN, analisando sua resposta você poderia evitar essa ultima coluna ou qualquer outra com um if, veja a minha nova resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado pessoal, consegui resolver voltando uma posição no length, já que o JS estava somando o conteúdo da última td que estava em branco. O código correto ficou assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function sumQuantity() {

       var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('qtd_recuperado');
       var sum = 0;



       for (i=0;i< (elements.length)-1;i++) {
         sum = sum + parseFloat(elements[i].innerHTML);

       };
          document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML=sum;
     }

       sumQuantity();
  </script>
```

Comment: Em vez de fazer isso, vc pode verificar se o valor está em branco com `if`. Outra coisa é que você pode escrever `sum += sum` em vez de `sum = sum +`.

Answer (score 0):

Para detectar a ocorrência de um NaN (Not a number) você deve usar a função Number.isNaN passando o valor.

```
var nan = 0 / 0;
var eNaN = Number.isNaN(nan); // eNaN vai ser true, pois zero sobre zero não é um número

var numero = parseInt("xpto");
if (Number.isNaN(numero))
    numero = 0; // zerando caso seja NaN
```