# Pra que serve o objeto Set do Javascript?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem

Já fiz uma pergunta parecida em relação à linguagem Python:
[Para que serve o set no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77699/para-que-serve-o-set-no-python).

Eu gostaria de saber se esse objeto `Set`no Javascript faz as mesmas coisas que o `set` do Python faz.

Exemplo:

```js
var numbers = new Set([1, 2, 3])

numbers.forEach(function (i) {
  console.log(i);
})
```

- Qual é a finalidade de `Set`?
- Quais navegadores o suportam? Atualmente (2018), é suportado em todos?
- Caso não tenha suporte em todos os navegadores, existe algum [Polyfill](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/194857/o-que-%C3%A9-polyfill)?

## Edição 1

- Quais são os valores que posso adicionar a um objeto `Set`?
- Posso ter uma coleção de string e int no mesmo objeto `Set`?
- Qual é o critério para determinar se um elemento já pertence ao objeto `Set`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss tem carta branca pra editar :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O `Set` é um **objeto** que permite setar **valores unicos**.

Você pode iniciar um `Set` vazio, ou iniciar já com algum conteudo a partir do construtor:

```
let foo = new Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
foo.add(6);
console.log(foo.entries());
```

Vai retornar:

```
SetIterator {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

### Iterando um Set

O `.entries` pode ser usado em um `for` para iterar, assim como pode usar o método `.forEach` do proprio `Set`, assim:

```
//O primeiro e o segundo argumento tem o mesmo valor
//o terceiro retorna o Set atual, pode ser interessante se usar a função para diferentes Sets
foo.forEach(function (valor1, valor2, currentSet) {
    console.log('set[' + chave + '] = ' + valor);

    console.log(currentSet); //Exibe o Set atual
});
```

Note que o `forEach` possui um segundo argumento:

```
.forEach(callback [, thisArg])
```

No lugar de `thisArg` você pode colocar outra coisa para que o `this` dentro do callback seja o que definiu, como podendo ser o `this` do escopo acima, exemplo:

```js
let foo = new Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

document.querySelector("#test").onclick = function () {
    foo.forEach(function (v1, v2, thisArg) {
        console.log(v1, v2, this);
    }, this);
};
```

```html
<button id="test">Testar</button>
```

Outra maneira de iterar é usar o proprio `Set` diretamente dentro de um `for...of` (ou `for...in`, se bem que este segundo não tem vantagem, já que só nos interessa o valor):

```
for (let valor of foo) {
     console.log(valor);
}
```

Creio que desta maneira fique até mais limpo que usar `.entries` ou `.forEach`, a vantagem do `.forEach` mesmo seria o uso de `callbacks` dinamicos, então ao invés de escrever três linhas assim:

```
for (let valor of foo) {
     meuCallback(valor);
}
```

Você escreveria somente uma assim:

```
foo.forEach(meuCallback);
```

Então pode usar `for...of` quando for apenas iterar e `forEach` quando tiver callbacks dinamicos.

---

### Suporte para o Set

Conforme o MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/forEach

O navegadores que suportam são:

- Chrome 38+
- Edge 12+
- IE 11+ (milagrosamente, essa eu não esperava)
- Safari 8+
- Firefox 25+

---

> Caso não tenha suporte em todos os navegadores, existe algum Polyfill?

Vou ser sincero, e entendam isto como opinião pessoal, Polyfill para isto parece um pouco de exagero, é sério, como o intuito é criar valores unicos uma simples checagem com `Array.indexOf` já resolveria antes de adicionar a um Array algo, por exemplo:

```
var x = [1,2,3];

//Supondo que este if seja executado por um callback e que os dados sejam dinamicos
var novo = 3;

if (x.indexOf(novo) === -1) {
    x.push(novo);
} else {
    console.log('Já adicionado');
}
```

Mas se acha que vai usar isto em muita coisa mesmo talvez um polyfill seja util. Assim que testar bem os polyfills citados nos comentários e tiver certeza que funcionam bem irei adicionar aqui (não costumo adicionar algo que não tenha testado ao menos uma vez).

---

### Convertendo para Array ou argumentos

Para converter para array pode usar os três pontos (isto se chama **Spread syntax** e isto **não** é suportado no Internet Explorer), assim:

```js
let foo = new Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

let arr = [...foo];

console.log(arr);
```

Ou pode passar para argumentos de uma função assim

```js
let foo = new Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

teste1(...foo);
teste2(...foo);

//Especificos
function teste1(a, b, c, d) {
    console.log("test1:", a, b, c, d);
}

//usando "arguments"
function teste2() {
    console.log("test2:", arguments);
}
```

Suporte para o Spread:

- Chrome 46+
- Edge 12+
- Firefox 16+
- Safari 8+

Outra maneira é usando o `Array.from`:

```
Array.from(foo);
```

Suporte:

- Chrome 45+
- Edge (aparentemente todas versões)
- Firefox 32+
- Safari 9+

---

### Detalhamentos sobre o Set

> Quais são os valores que posso adicionar a um objeto Set?

Qualquer coisa mesmo que poderia adicionar a uma variavel ou array, ele funciona como um array mesmo, mas simplesmente tem o detalhe do controle de valores unicos

> Posso ter uma coleção de string e int no mesmo objeto Set?

Sim, suporta qualquer coisa, pode até ter `Set` dentro de `Set`, mas uma coisa precisa ficar claro, os valores de subitens adicionado de Objetos são como referencias, ou seja o valor **não é copiado** ele é referenciado, isso em Arrays e Object também, porque isso é como o JavaScript é, claro que você pode copiar/clonar um objeto inteiro, mas isto é outra história.

> Qual é o critério para determinar se um elemento já pertence ao objeto Set?

Pode usar o `.has`, vale notar que é como disse, é tudo como referencia, então por exemplo:

```js
var a = {};
var b = {};

console.log(a === b); //Retorna FALSE
```

Apesar de semelhantes são objetos diferentes, então ao fazer isto:

```js
var a = {};
var meuSet = new Set;

meuSet.add(a);

console.log(meuSet.has({})); //Retorna FALSE
console.log(meuSet.has(a)); //Retorna TRUE
```

O `meuSet.has(a)` retorna TRUE porque esta checando o proprio objeto referenciado na variavel `a`, isto não tem haver com o `Set`, mas sim como o JavaScript funciona (tal comportamento é semelhante em muitas linguagens)

Comment: Bacana, a resposta tem alguns detalhes e funcionalidades importante a serem considerados. +1

Answer (score 4):

Basicamente cria uma coleção de objetos únicos. É novo por no ES6, por isso ainda não é compatível com todos os navegadores. Abaixo um link de compatibilidades.

Diferente de uma coleção comum ou dicionário, você não recupera um objeto diretamente por uma chave, o objeto já é uma chave, que deve ser única.  Dá pra notar isso pelo modo como adicionamos valores:

```
var colecao = new Set();
colecao.add(1);
colecao.add("teste");
```

Note que pode ser adicionando qualquer tipo de objeto. Tem métodos como `has` para saber se um item já existe na coleção, mas para recuperar os objetos, deve-se iterar, aqui em exemplo:

```
colecao.forEach(function(valor) {
  console.log(valor);
});
```

Me parece um objeto com uma função parecida com *"vou adicionando itens que quero marcar, como executados ou existentes, e verificar depois se estão na coleção"*, uma vez que não dá pra obter diretamente um objeto da coleção.

Aqui mais informação e também ao final um chart de compatibilidade dos navegadores: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Atualizado aqui em 12/07/2018:

```
Chrome  Edge    Firefox Internet Explorer   Opera   Safari
38      12      13      11                  25      8
```

Ah, não conheço nenhum *Polyfill* para contornar o problema de compatibilidade.

**EDIT**: para responder as novas perguntas:

***Quais são os valores que posso adicionar a um objeto Set?***
Qualquer tipo de objeto.

***Posso ter uma coleção de string e int no mesmo objeto Set?***
Sim, inclusive no exemplo acima demonstra isso.

***Qual é o critério para determinar se um elemento já pertence ao objeto Set?***
Boa pergunta, provavelmente algum tipo de hash, apenas suposição aqui.

Comment: Polyfill seria implementar do zero? Não parece complicado fazer

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado ia falar agora. Estou pensando em fazer um :p

Comment: Não parece ser muito difícil mesmo @JeffersonQuesado, um prototype pra estender e ficar bem transparente e ir adicionando itens num array, dá até um código pra por no *github* :P

Comment: Já tem @RicardoPontual. Dá uma olhada no [link](https://github.com/jfriend00/ES6-Set/blob/master/set.js)

Comment: Caramba santa velocidade batman, não deu tempo nem de pensar.. :)

Comment: @RicardoPontual ué?  dessa vez você **chegou atrasado**. Implementaram primeiro que você. Tum dum tss!

Comment: Estava pensando na funcionalidade disso, e lembrei que certa vez tive de processar um arquivo texto que algumas informações se repetem em linhas alternadas, e só precisa usar a primeira, então basicamente pra controlar criei uma lista e adicionava a chave dessa linha e via se já existia. Esse objeto cairia como uma luva pra isso

Comment: A ideia é não precisar verificar para adicionar se tem ou não. Isso pra mim é ótimo.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters mas põe atrasado nisso, o último *commit*  foi em 2014!!!

Answer (score 4):

<sup>Ministério da Saúde adverte: esta resposta possui altas concentrações de teoria</sup>

## Set

O objeto `Set` é definido no ECMAScript 2015 como uma *keyed colletion*, junto com outros três objetos: [`Map`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/313916/5878), [`WeakMap`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/314184/5878) e `WeakSet`, como sendo uma coleção de *valores da linguagem ECMAScript*, sendo que valores distintos ocorrer apenas uma vez como um elemento do conjunto - valores distintos são discriminados utilizando o algoritmo de comparação `SameValueZero`.

- [ECMAScript 2015, 23.2 Set Objects](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-set-objects)

Conjuntos devem ser implementados utilizando tabelas *hash* ou outros mecanismos que, na média, proveem um tempo de acesso que seja sublinear ao número de elementos do conjunto. Qualquer característica comentada nesta resposta será em relação à especificação de implementação previsto pela ECMAScript e pode não representar fielmente o modelo implementado pelos navegadores.

> São considerados como *valores da linguagem ECMAScript* os tipos [*Undefined*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-undefined-type), [*Null*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-null-type), [*Boolean*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-boolean-type), [*String*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-string-type), [*Symbol*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-symbol-type), [*Number*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type) e [*Object*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-type)

### Construtor Set

O *Set* é o objeto intrínseco [`%Set%`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-well-known-intrinsic-objects) e, também, valor inicial da propriedade global `Set`. Quando chamado como construtor, cria e inicializa um novo conjunto, porém, mesmo sendo *callable*, `Set` não pode ser chamado como função, disparando uma exceção quando o feito: *Uncaught TypeError: Constructor Set requires 'new'*.

```js
const s1 = new Set();  // Ok
const s2 = Set();  // Exception
```

O construtor `Set` foi projetado para ser herdado por outras classes. Classes que herdam de `Set` e querem manter o comportamento desta devem chamar `super` em sua inicialização para que seja efetivamente criado e inicializado o novo conjunto no estado necessário para suportar toda a estrutura prevista em `Set.prototype`.

```js
class Numbers extends Set {
  constructor (numbers) {
    super(numbers)
  }
}


const n = new Numbers([1, 2, 3]);

console.log(...n);
```

### Inicialização de um `Set`

```
Set ( [ iterable ] )
```

Quando o construtor `Set` é chamado com um parâmetro opcional `iterable` os seguintes passos são executados:

1. Se `newTarget` for `undefined`, lança a exceção `TypeError`;
2. Define `set` como `OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor(NewTarget, "%SetPrototype%", «‍[[SetData]]» )`;
3. Se `set` for uma [*conclusão abrupta*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-returnifabrupt), retorne;
4. Define o slot interno `[[SetData]]` de `set` como uma nova lista vazia ([`List`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-list-and-record-specification-type));
5. Se `iterable` não estiver presente, define-o como `undefined`;
6. Se `iterable` for `undefined` ou `null`, define-o como `undefined`;
7. Senão:

   - Define `adder` como `Get(set, "add")`;
   - Se `adder` for uma *conclusão abrupta*, retorne;
   - Se `adder` não for *callable*, lança uma exceção `TypeError`;
   - Define `iter` como `GetIterator(iterable)`;
   - Se `iter` for uma *conclusão abrupta*, retorne;
8. Se `iter` for `undefined`, retorne `set`;
9. Repita:

   - Define `next` como `IteratorStep(iter)`;
   - Se `next` for uma *conclusão abrupta*, retorne;
   - Se `next` for `false`, retorne `set`;
   - Define `nextValue` como `IteratorValue(next)`;
   - Se `nextValue` for uma *conclusão abrupta*, retorne;
   - Define `status` como `Call(adder, set, «nextValue.[[value]]»)`;
   - Se `status` for uma *conclusão abrupta*, retorne `IteratorClose(iter, status)`;

Perceba que a própria inicialização chama o método `add` para adicionar os valores de entrada, então para entender melhor, será necessário analisar também este método.

## Adicionando valores

```
Set.prototype.add ( value )
```

Quando o método `add` do conjunto é chamado, os seguintes passos são executados:

1. Define `S` como o objeto `this`;
2. Se `Type(S)` não for *Object* lança uma exceção `TypeError`;
3. Se `S` não possuir um slot interno `[[SetData]]`, lança uma exceção `TypeError`;
4. Define `entries` como a lista que é o valor do slot interno `[[SetData]]`;
5. Repita para cada `e` que pertence a `entries`:

   - Se `e` não for vazio e `SameValueZero(e, value)` retornar `true`, return `S`;
6. Se `value` for `-0`, define-o como `+0`;
7. Adiciona `value` como último valor de `entries`;
8. Retorne `S`;

Um algoritmo bastante simples, porém, não trivial dada a dependência que há com o retorno de `SameValueZero`. Este `SameValueZero` é um algorimo de comparação implementado no ECMAScript e precisamos entendê-lo também.

### Comparação `SameValueZero`

```
SameValueZero(x, y)
```

[`SameValueZero`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-samevaluezero) é um algortimo de comparação implementado no ECMAScript que segue os seguintes passos:

1. Se `x` for uma *conclusão abrupta*, retorne;
2. Se `y` for uma *conclusão abrupta*, retorne;
3. Se `Type(x)` é diferente de `Type(y)`, retorne `false`;
4. Se `Type(x)` é *Undefined*, retorne `true`;
5. Se `Type(x)` é *Null*, retorne `true`;
6. Se `Type(x)` é *Number*, então:

   - Se `x` é `NaN` e `y` é `NaN`, retorne `true`;
   - Se `x` é `-0` e `y` é `+0`, retorne `true`;
   - Se `x` é `+0` e `y` é `-0`, retorne `true`;
   - Se `x` possui o mesmo valor numérico de `y`, retorne `true`;
   - Senão retorne `false`;

     7. Se `Type(x)` é *String*, então:
   - Se `x` e `y` forem exatamente a mesma sequência de unidades de código (mesmo comprimento e mesmas unidades de código nos respectivos índices), retorne `true`;
   - Senão, retorne `false`;

     8. Se `Type(x)` é *Boolean*, então:
   - Se `x` e `y` são ambos `true` ou ambos `false`, retorne `true`;
   - Senão, retorne `false`;

     9. Se `Type(x)` é *Symbol*, então:
   - Se `x` e `y` são o mesmo valor de símbolo, retorne `true`;
   - Senão, retorne `false`;

     10. Retorne `true` de `x` e `y` são o mesmo objeto, senão retorne `false`;

> **Nota:** importante notar que mesmo [`NaN` sendo diferente de `NaN`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/211227/5878), dentro do algoritmo `SameValueZero`, se ambas as entradas forem numéricas e iguais a `NaN`, o retorno será `true`.

## Perguntas

Dada a breve introdução de `Set`, vamos aos questionamentos:

**Para que serve o `Set`?**

Serve para representar uma coleção de valores não uniformes e únicos. A unicidade se dá pela própria definição de conjuntos da matemática, que afirma que se dados dois conjuntos A e B, tal que A está contido em B e B está contido em A, então A = B, onde diz-se que A está contido em B se para todo elemento pertencente ao A pertence também ao B.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim como descrito na introdução, a implementação de conjunto costuma ser feito através de uma tabela *hash*, que possui relação 1:1 entre a chave e valor, o que, em algumas linguagens, faz com que a ordem dos elementos dentro do conjunto não seja garantida, mas que o tempo de acesso seja, na média, independente da quantidade de elementos.

[Como pode a busca de um elemento em um conjunto ser O(1)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/306024/5878) (trata sobre isso em Python)

Não achei nada oficial quanto à implementação do `Set` em JavaScript, mas eu diria que pode-se utilizar o `Set` quando você precisa de uma coleção de itens únicos, não dependendo da ordem dos mesmos e que o acesso a eles seja rápido.

**Quais navegadores o suportam? Atualmente (2018), é suportado em todos?**

**Caso não tenha suporte em todos os navegadores, existe algum Polyfill?**

Vide outras respostas.

**Quais são os valores que posso adicionar a um objeto Set?**

Todos os previstos como tipos da linguagem ECMAScript: [*Undefined*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-undefined-type), [*Null*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-null-type), [*Boolean*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-boolean-type), [*String*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-string-type), [*Symbol*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-symbol-type), [*Number*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type) e [*Object*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-type).

**Posso ter uma coleção de string e int no mesmo objeto Set?**

Pode, o tipo será considerado dentro do algoritmo `SameValueZero` que, se forem de tipos diferentes, já são considerados como objetos diferentes.

**Qual é o critério para determinar se um elemento já pertence ao objeto Set?**

Pode variar conforme a implementação, mas acredito que todos devem satisfazer o algoritmo `SameValueZero` descrito anteriormente. Muitas linguagens utilizam mecanismos de *hash* do valor de entrada como a própria chave do conjunto, bastando apenas calcular o *hash* do objeto de entrada e verificando se o mesmo existe na tabela atual.

Comment: Resposta com disclaimer do ministério da saúde? Hahaha, boa

Comment: Eu acho que um pouco de LaTeX na parte de teoria dos conjuntos ajudaria na leitura.