# Para que serve o objeto WeakMap?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem

- Como funciona o objeto `WeakMap`?
- Qual é a diferença entre ele e um `Object` (que é o mais comum no Javascript)?
- Qual é a diferença entre `WeakMap` e [Map](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/313916/pra-que-serve-o-objeto-map-em-javascript)?
- Em quais navegadores posso usar?

Comment: Quem deu os negativos poderia explicar? O que pode ser melhorado na pergunta? Ou é simplesmente porque discorda da forma que pergunto?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/314293/64969

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recomendo a leitura da [pergunta sobre `Map`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/313916/pra-que-serve-o-objeto-map-em-javascript) primeiro. O tipo `WeakMap` funciona exatamente como o `Map`, com as seguintes principais diferenças:

1. Só aceita objetos como chave
2. Não é enumerável, ou seja, não permite listar as chaves
3. **Referências às chaves são sempre referências fracas**

A última está em negrito porque é o motivo do `WeakMap` existir. Uma "referência fraca" neste contexto significa que o uso de determinado objeto como chave num `WeakMap` **não conta** do ponto de vista do coletor de lixo. Se não existir nenhuma outra referência a um objeto utilizado como chave num `WeakMap`, o valor correspondente a essa chave no `WeakMap` é liberado para ser coletado pelo *garbage collector*.

Answer (score 4):

### Como funciona o objeto WeakMap?

`WeakMap` é um objeto do `Javascript` que fornece um dicionário de objetos, ou seja, um objeto que armazena dados no format chave/valor.

Como um dicionário, ele funciona baseado numa chave, ou seja, para as operações de incluir/recuperar/excluir é usando uma chave para identificar o objeto.

Aqui um exemplo da criação de um dicionário e as operações básicas:

```js
var dic = new WeakMap()

//chaves
var chaveA = { chave: 'A' };
var chaveB = { chave: 'B' };
var chaveC = { chave: 'C' };

// adicionando objetos
dic.set(chaveA, 1);
dic.set(chaveB, "dois");
dic.set(chaveC, new Date(2018,06,13));

// verificando objetos
console.log("existe objeto 'A':" + dic.has(chaveA));

// recuperando
console.log("valor do objeto 'A':" + dic.get(chaveA));
console.log("valor do objeto 'B':" + dic.get(chaveB));
console.log("valor do objeto 'C':" + dic.get(chaveC));

// excluindo
dic.delete(chaveA);
console.log("existe objeto 'A':" + dic.has(chaveA));
```

### Qual é a diferença entre ele e um Object (que é o mais comum no Javascript)?

Principais diferenças:

- não tem um método para recuperar um objeto, como WeakMap tem o `get()`;
- não tem um método para atribuir valores como o `set()` do WeakMap, é necessário usar o operador `=`;
- não tem um método para limpar as propriedades como o `clear()` do WeakMap;

### Qual é a diferença entre WeakMap e Map?

Principais diferenças:

- Map é iterável e por isso suporta `forEach`, já WeakMap não.
- A chave de um objeto Map pode ser qualquer objeto (`string`, `number`, etc), enquanto o WeakMap deve ser um `Object`.

### Em quais navegadores posso usar?

Segundo o **developer.mozila.org** em 13/07/2018 a compatibilidade é:

```
Chrome  Firefox     Internet Explorer   Opera           Safari
36      6.0 (6.0)   11                  Não suportado   Não suportado
```

[developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap)

Comment: Como assim `Map` não permite recuperar o objeto?

Comment: Você tem razão @JeffersonQuesado, o `Set` não permite recuperar, já corrigi a resposta, obrigado por apontar